# How does WordPress track that a certain User is Logged-In

Tags: login, post-status

I am trying to identify the elements that WP uses to track that a user is logged in at any given time.

(1) I know WP sets a `COOKIE` for tracking

Does anyone know if WordPress also sets a `_SESSION` variable as well?

Does anyone know if WordPress records login status in a `DB Table` as well?

Is there anything else WP uses to track a user as being logged-in?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before core version 4.0 the authentication depended only on cookies.

Starting with 4.0 core introduced its own sessions (`WP_Session_Tokens`) to better handle security things. Note that these are **not** PHP sessions, they are implemented purely by WordPress and use user meta as storage.

Unfortunately I don't think there is any clear documentation for this feature. From quick search it was discussed and implemented in ticket [#20276 Tie nonces and cookies to expirable sessions](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20276).

Comment: `Unfortunately I don't think there is any clear documentation for this feature.` Thank you @Rarst. I have found this to be that answer to my questions.